# Container view controller communication with childViewControllers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a container view controller with 3 child UIViewController subclasses (added with addChildViewController). I want one of my child view controllers to do something when something is dropped from my container view controller onto it. I'm having trouble grasping how this communication should happen. If I try making a delegate, I get an error in my child view controller because I would both subclasses to import each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're having a problem *compiling* your app because of mutual .h files `importing` each other, right?

> **Edit:** upon reading your question again, I'm not 100% clear on which view controller needs to call which other one. If I mixed up the
>   roles of parent and child view controller in my solution, just switch
>   them.  The techniques below let you communicate between any two view
>   controllers (parent and child, sibling and sibling, etc.)

There's a number of ways to handle this.  If you want to stay with a `delegate` pattern, you could simply rewrite the header to avoid the `#import` in one of the .h files:

ParentViewController.h:

```
#import "ChildViewController.h"

@interface ParentViewController: UIViewController {
@private
   ChildViewController* childVc;
}

- (void) doSomething;
```

ChildViewController.h

```
@class ParentViewController;   // NOT #import!

@interface ChildViewController: UIViewController {
@private
   ParentViewController* parentVc;
}
```

ChildViewController.m

```
#import "ParentViewController.h"
```

This should avoid the circular dependency that keeps your app from compiling.

Now, although the above works, I might choose another solution, for the sake of cleanliness.  Use a `protocol`.  The parent can implement the protocol and then the child only needs to have a delegate that implements the protocol:

```
#import "MyProtocol.h"

@interface ParentViewController: UIViewController<MyProtocol> {

}

- (void) doSomething;
```

In MyProtocol.h:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
 - (void) doSomething;
@end
```

Then in ChildViewController.h

```
#import "MyProtocol.h"

@interface ChildViewController: UIViewController {
@private
   id<MyProtocol> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyProtocol> delegate;
```

And in ChildViewController.m:

```
   [delegate doSomething];
```

Or, you could avoid using delegates altogether, and [communicate between the controllers using `NSNotificationCenter`](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/dead-simple-nsnotification-example-iphone/), which decouples them a bit, and avoids your compiler circularity (bidirectional dependency).

[Here are the Apple docs on NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I agree with the use of protocols here. The child should not have a reference to the parent ever. This is not an appropriate place to use NSNotificationCenter however. You would use that to broadcast a message to numerous objects, not just the parent object in a container. Delegation is the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just go:

```
MyChildViewController *myChildViewController = (MyChildViewController *)[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[myChildViewController doWhatever];
```

?
That should let you message the child view controller at the first index of the array childViewControllers (which is a property on UIViewController).

Comment: I could, but I don't see how this is much different than simply defining nested view controllers and using them. If this doesn't break any design rules, I would be more than happy to implement this method.

Comment: I can't actually speak to best practice.